# windows vpn: Set up using powershell, how?

Tags: windows, vpn

With ssh, we can execute a few commands on the server, and have a simple set of commands on a client that bring up the vpn , and re-establish it if it goes down.

How/where are docs to do something similar using powershell and the windows vpn functionality?

- create the server listening point
- connect from client to server, for one or both of below needs
- monitor connection, and if it goes down rebuild the vpn

We have two kinds of vpn needs:

- on the client, traffic on port 80 to a specific host should get passed over the vpn
- server to server, ability to map a share from one server to the other (for sql log shipping)

We are looking for a SIMPLE, direct, peer to peer approach here (which is easy to do w SSH, the real problem, when you get down to it, is that there is no native SSH support in windows!).

We CANNOT use solutions that depend on:

- Active Directory
- Fancy setup stuff

We need a way, using built in VPN and/or Direct Access and/or Other features, to make a vpn between two stand alone servers.

The only thing found so far is this ms doc:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=2555

which has a lot of group policy stuff which is not relevant, and does not seem to directly tackle what I am looking for.

This environment is %100 Win2012-R2

Answer (score 0):

If you SR stuck using VPN then that paper is a decent resource.  You should also look into winrm configuration for remote shells/management (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426(v=vs.85).aspx). However if you have an all windows environment, that means you can use directaccess and can avoid VPN altogether from your devices (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759144.aspx ) as well as maintain security over the endpoints (which is where traditional VPN falls down, where the best you can do is network access protection and network access controls)

Comment: Direct Access looks really cool! (How is it I never knew about it? Right, my msce expired many years ago....). However, direct access appears not-appro for machine to machine comm (this is for software to talk, not users), and it has domain dependence (ain't no domain here, just stand alone servers), and it seems to req ipv6, which we don't have.